Resource limitation issues with loki
I have deployed promtail and loki separately using helm.
I observed the following error in the promtail logs
level=warn ts=2024-05-30T07:02:56.747829793Z caller=client.go:419 component=client host=hw-loki.monitoring.svc:3100 msg="error sending batch, will retry" status=429 tenant= error="server returned HTTP status 429 Too Many Requests (429): Ingestion rate limit exceeded for user fake (limit: 4194304 bytes/sec) while attempting to ingest '50527' lines totaling '1048502' bytes, reduce log volume or contact your Loki administrator to see if the limit can be increased"

Will this cause my loki to not collect data and how should I change my loki configuration?
I don't know where to start yet.
